# json to shapefile in javascript

Tags: shapefile, javascript, json, web

I know, there are some libraries to convert .shp to .json even with javascript, but haven't found a way to convert .json back into .shp that could be implemented in web enviroment. 
Do you know or have experience with something? Or what are my possibilities?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to do with pure JavaScript as it creates 3 binary files. Your best bet would be to setup a OGR web service that would take json in parameter and output a zipped SHP. Look at Ogre, it may help:

http://ogre.adc4gis.com/

**EDIT:**

I didn't test it myself, but it is indeed now possible to save shapefile from javascript:

https://github.com/mapbox/shp-write

Comment: That's not true. It just involves writing binary data... which is not very easy, but completely possible: https://code.google.com/p/js2shapefile/source/browse/trunk/src/JSShapefile_Generic.js

Comment: That answer is outdated for now; it can be done with pure JS.

Comment: Shapefiles can be created in javascript. You can see a working example on my website to convert csv to shapefile in pure JavaScript. http://geospatialearth.in/Point2Poly

Answer (score 4):

I am working on one here:

https://github.com/morganherlocker/geojson2shape

It is javascript, but it runs server side, which I would bet all of the solutions require. This one is essentially a node.js wrapper around ogr2ogr. It would be easy enough to set up a simple node.js server though that accepts geojson and sends back the url to a shp download (that is how I am using it).

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to convert to shapefile in JavaScript, in the client side. The following library accomplishes this. Perhaps it is outdated (2012-2013), but at least it shows the concept.

> ## JS2Shapefile
>
> JS2Shapefile is a Javascript class to create ESRI shapefiles directly in the browser. It also includes a couple of helper classes for creating and saving the binary data in browsers where that isn't fully supported (anything other than Chrome).

This library creates and saves the binary files in the browser using the HTML5 Filesystem API.

> The HTML5 specs introduce the ability to work with binary data in Javascript. Binary data can be created using the ArrayBuffer TypedArray object. See http://www.khronos.org/registry/typedarray/specs/latest/ - this is currently implemented in browsers including Chrome and Firefox.

It uses different approaches for different browsers.

> In summary: in Chrome we can create the data and save it to file entirely natively. On other browsers we need various levels of help. JS2Shapefile has been written to use these intermediate helper parts but if the client is guaranteed to be Chrome or something else implementing DataView, BlobBuilder, and Filesystem APIs, all that could be removed.

It has been [featured in the ArcGIS website](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=76abc91cf91445cf957943955d35fb0c). The [original repository](https://code.google.com/archive/p/js2shapefile/) was located at Google Code, but it is also [available in GitHub](https://github.com/borisdev/js2shapefile). Here is another [blog post](https://nordpil.com/blog/js2shapefile/) about it.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest library called shp-write (https://github.com/mapbox/shp-write), which writes Geojson to Shapefile. That's pure Javascript library, without any server-side processing. Understandably, it requires modern browser.

Personally, since I'm not familiar with RequireJS, I had some difficulties to get it working. But after all, it's really simple to use, for example, to download .zip'ed shapefiles

```
shpwrite.download(geojsonData);
```

is all you need; and it's working well.